# Symfony ACL => ObjectIdentity() is already associated with an ACL

Tags: symfony, acl, symfony-2.1, fixtures

I want to use ACL with Symfony 2 and load them in my fixtures.

The following code works perfectly but if I uncomment `array('myprivateroom', 'user1', 'view'),` I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\AclAlreadyExistsException]  ObjectIdentity(1, Acme\RoomBundle\Entity\Room) is already associated with an ACL.
```

I think the problem is here `$acl = $aclProvider-createAcl(ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($room));` but I don't know how to solve it.

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $datas = array(
        array('myprivateroom', 'admin', 'owner'),
        //array('myprivateroom', 'user1', 'view'),
        array('mypublicroom', 'user1', 'owner'),
    );

    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        // creating the ACL
        $room = $this->getReference($data[0]);
        $aclProvider = $this->container->get('security.acl.provider');
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($room);
        //problem here when I uncomment array('myprivateroom', 'user1', 'view'),
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl(ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($room));

        // retrieving the security identity of the user
        $user = $this->getReference($data[1]);
        $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

        //create mask
        $builder = new MaskBuilder();
        $builder->add($data[2]);
        $mask = $builder->get();

        // grant owner access
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, $mask);
        $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
    }
}
```

## Thanks

Update:
If I do 2 arrays like

```
$datas = array(
    array('myprivateroom', 'admin', 'owner'),
    array('mypublicroom', 'user1', 'owner'),
);

$datas2 = array(
    array('myprivateroom', 'user1', 'view'),
);
```

And 2 foreach but, in the second, I replace `$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl(ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($room));` by `$acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);`, it works perfectly but I don't think it's the right way, and the following doesn't work.

```
try {
    $acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);
} catch (AclNotFoundException $e) {
    $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem as you and I've solved it like this.

```
try {
    $acl = $this->get('security.acl.provider')->findAcl($idObjeto);
} catch (\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\AclNotFoundException $e) {
    $acl = $this->get('security.acl.provider')->createAcl($idObjeto);
}
```

I do not explain very well why. The only different is "\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\AclNotFoundException"

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming a bit late but in case someone needs to understand what happened with your code. If you loop through this array :

```
$datas = array(
    array('myprivateroom', 'admin', 'owner'),
    array('myprivateroom', 'user1', 'view'),
    array('mypublicroom', 'user1', 'owner'),
);
```

you'll be using :

```
 $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl(ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($room));
```

on first and second loop. It will try to create an access control list (ACL) for `'myprivateroom'` twice. That's why it throws an error saying you already have a list for this Room entity.

```
ObjectIdentity(1, Acme\RoomBundle\Entity\Room) is already associated with an ACL
```

A good way to solve it is to try if it has an ACL, and create it if it doesn't (answer provided by @JGrinon). Otherwise you can organize your data in a multidimensionnal array and loop through it :

```
// PHP array but you could use a JSON array to be clearer
$datas = array(
    array('myprivateroom',
        array(
            array('admin', 'owner'),
            array('user1', 'view1')
        )
    ),
    array('mypublicroom',
        array(
            array('user1', 'owner'),
        )
    ),
);

// Call ACL Provider service before the loop
$aclProvider = $this->container->get('security.acl.provider');

// Loop through the array
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    // Get the room name
    $room = $this->getReference($data[0]);
    $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($room);
    // The list is created only once for each room
    $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl(ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($room));

    // Loop through the list of users and associated rights
    $list = $this->getReference($data[1]);
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        // Retrieving the security identity of the user
        $user = $row[0];
        $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

        // Create Mask
        $builder = new MaskBuilder();
        $builder->add($row[1]);
        $mask = $builder->get();

        // Grant access
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, $mask);
    };

    // Update Access Control List
    $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
}
```

Hope this helps ;)